# Converting Data Frame to Time Series using R

Tags: r, time, time-series, series

I have a csv in the following format.

```
  Date      Sales
 1/3/2005     800
 1/4/2005    9000
 1/5/2005    1300
 1/6/2005     400
 1/7/2005     100
 1/8/2005     190
```

I tried to get it into a time series format using:

```
ts(dataframe)
```

But it was giving a weird output. Any assistance or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Is the first row Dzte Jan 3 or March 1?

Comment: I think you just want something like this `dataframe$Date <- as.Date(dataframe$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")`, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Its January third so month/day/year.

Comment: I get the following error when I try to convert it. Error in as.date(h.data, format = "%m/%d/%y") : 
  Cannot coerce to date format

Comment: Use an upper Y: `as.Date(h.data, format = "%m/%d/%Y")` That works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date format is m/d/yyyy (modified):

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Date      Sales
 1/3/2005     800
 1/4/2005    9000
 1/5/2005    1300
 1/6/2005     400
 1/7/2005     100
 1/8/2005     190",  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mydate <- function(x) {
  c(year = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "/"))[3]),
    month = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "/"))[1]),
    day = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "/"))[2]))
}

(myts <- ts(df$Sales, 
            start = mydate(head(df$Date, 1)),
            freq = 365.25))
```

Comment: It's m/d/yyyy according to the discussion under the question.